# New column that tells when observation first occurred

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column 'First Appearance that tells me when the observation first occurred using the tidyverse package.

For Example: If I have

| Year | Observation |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | A |
| 2000 | B |
| 2001 | A |
| 2001 | C |

I would like the following outcome.

| Year | Observation | First Appearance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | A | 2000 |
| 2000 | B | 2000 |
| 2001 | A | 2000 |
| 2001 | C | 2001 |

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Observation) %>% 
  mutate(FirstObservation = min(Year)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

**Output**

```
   Year Observation FirstObservation
  <int> <chr>                  <int>
1  2000 A                       2000
2  2000 B                       2000
3  2001 A                       2000
4  2001 C                       2001
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L), Observation = c("A", 
"B", "A", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is asked about `tidyverse`, still, I include a variant using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,FistAppearance:= min(Year), Observation]
df
       Year Observation FistAppearance
1: 2000           A           2000
2: 2000           B           2000
3: 2001           A           2000
4: 2001           C           2001
```